# Multiple async tasks not executing properly

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to start 6 async tasks at a time in `onCreate()` of the activity. But I noticed following:

a) If I stay on same activity all the async tasks' `doInBackground()` execute properly.

b) If I switch to some other activity, only 4 or 5 async tasks' `doInBackground()` executes. Last `async` task's `doInBackground()` never executes.

Can someone tell what I might be doing wrong. I am staring different asynctasks in a for loop. If I do this in onStart(), then all the async tasks are executed again if I switch to this activity. Please help.
Here is the sample code:

```
For(int i=0;i<7;i++){
webServiceTask= WebServiceTask.getInstance();
webServiceTask.execute("");
}
```

Comment: Post your code. Seems like what you really want is an `IntentService`, though.

Comment: Do you cancel any of your async tasks in onPause() or onStop()? Also, keep in mind that when you start another activity, and your activity hosting the asynctasks goes to the background because of that, there may be no guarantee that your process is kept alive. Some of your AsyncTasks may never run because your process was killed. Finally, but not sure if this is important to you, AsyncTasks are run on worker threads from a thread pool. Depending on your Android version this pool may vary in size (even size == 1). This can explain why 4 (or 5) tasks are run immediately, but the others not (yet)

Comment: hey thanks... I just forgot this thing..:)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should consider some of the following points:

- Is the WebServiceTask retrieving any information that is worth persisting (i.e. not very volatile, with a high risk of the user requesting the same data over and over again): in that case you can offload your work to an (Intent)Service and communicate the result back to your app via a ResultReceiver, or a ContentProvider (just to name a few).
- AsyncTasks are not guaranteed to run to completion if no Activity or Service is around to keep your app's process alive.
- If it is ok that the WebServiceTasks run after eachother, then you can probably also change your code to use only one AsyncTask that sequentially performs those tasks. You can even consider implementing AsyncTask's progress reporting mechanism.
- If the operations performed by the AsyncTask(s) have no meaning once the Activity is closed, be sure to .cancel() them in your onStop() or onPause() lifecycle methods.
- Keep bullet 3 of Ed Rowland's answer in mind, which I also posted in my earlier comment to your question.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You need a Service of some kind to keep your process alive after the user switches away. Once your activity loses focus, Android is free to shut down your process altogether. Or your Activity. Either will cause problems, particularly if you are  using the context of an Activity that has been shut down.

The Right Thing to Do (tm) is to implement a Service, and pass the operations off to the service for execution.

There are any of a bunch of reasons why only four tasks are running concurrently. Off the top of my head:

- HttpConnection pools connections to servers, and throttles the
  maximum number of connetions to any given server to some reasonable
  value. 4 sounds about right.
- your target server is throttling the number of simultaneous connections.
- Your thread pool isn't as large as you think it is. Starting an API 16 (I think) the    default threadpool size is one thread! (!!) Rationale: apparently Android OS developers got fed up with Android app developers doing threading wrong. Is it possible your tasks are executing serially? That would more or less fit the symptoms you describe.

But that's kind of a separate issue.

Comment: Actually only the 3rd bullet is a reason why a limited nr of tasks is running. The other two are reasons why asynctasks are not running to completion (but are "running" nevertheless). The "Right Thing to Do" cannot be inferred from the information given in the question. For example: if the AsyncTasks are only retrieving information that holds any value while the app is running, then implementing a Service is not required. An asynctasks that is terminated in onPause() or onStop() can be most suitable (depending on the volatility of the data that is retrieved).

Comment: Point well taken. Async tasks are appropriate if operations aren't required to complete. Although one would think that if the OP wasn't concerned about the operations completing, he wouldn't have asked the question in the first place. Regards.